# Visibility of annotated methods in Eclipse e4 RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

All examples for annotated methods like postConstruct() or preDestroy() always have a public visibility. But the DI mechanism still works if I reduce the visibility to protected or private.

As those methojds only get called by the framework, what should be their visibility?

I never call those methods myself and I don't want anyone other than the framework invoking them - so they should not be public. But they are an external interface to my class.

What is the preferred method here?

Comment: I don't recall seeing anything recommending a particular method. Internally the injection system calls `Method.setAccessible(true)` which makes it public for that call.

Comment: It always stings me, when I'm create a new command or part, that the default generated methods are public. I have configured my Eclipse that I get a warning for each public/protected method without Javadoc. But those methods don't feel like API for public access ... I think I'll make them private in the future.